# using jQuery .each on a javascript variable before appending to screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

If i have some basic html that is saved in a variable $html and I want to use an each (jQuery) statement on it before appending to the page and I want to look in this string for each instance of a class and ammend $html.

This is what I was thinking...

```
$('.flipper', $html).each(function(){
    var frontContent    =   $(this).find('.front > .content');
    var backContent     =   $(this).find('.back > .content');
    $(this).append('<div class="background"><div class="content">' + frontContent.html() + '<div class="back">' + backContent.html() + '</div></div></div>');
    console.log($html);
});
```

this doesnt run - i guess because i am trying to update an element on the page rather than one stored in a variable

can I still use the each ?

Cheers

Comment: please share the relevant html

Comment: is `$html` is string variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like $html is a string, not a dom element reference... in that case changes made to the elements in the loop will not be reflected in the original string.

Try something like

```
var html = '';

var $html = $(html);
$('.flipper', $html).each(function () {
    var frontContent = $(this).find('.front > .content');
    var backContent = $(this).find('.back > .content');
    $(this).append('<div class="background"><div class="content">' + frontContent.html() + '<div class="back">' + backContent.html() + '</div></div></div>');
});

console.log($html[0].outerHTML);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yB4WK/2/)

Comment: hmm.. this isnt working... it doesnt run the each loop .. but if i have this var $html = $(html); console.log($html, "here"); it shows each element in firebug but greyed out

Comment: @Dan Did you try the fiddle

Comment: @Dan I'm getting the o/p as `<div id="ct"><div class="flipper"><div class="front"><div class="content">front</div></div><div class="back"><div class="content">back</div></div><div class="background"><div class="content">front<div class="back">back</div></div></div></div><div class="flipper"><div class="front"><div class="content">front 2</div></div><div class="back"><div class="content">back 2</div></div><div class="background"><div class="content">front 2<div class="back">back 2</div></div></div></div></div> ` it has background div

Comment: @Dan in your case you need to use `.filter()` instead of `.find()` since the `flipper` is not a child element... try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yB4WK/4/

Comment: thanks.. that worked.. but how at the end of the each statement do i just return the whole of $html so i can just replace html with $html?

Comment: @Dan just use `html = $html[0].outerHTML;` like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yB4WK/6/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$($html).find('.flipper').each(....);
```